# How to join paths in Beam FileSystem

Tags: scala, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam, dataflow

I am figuring out something basic about Beam [FileSystems](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileSystems.html). What's the analogous of this in Beam?

```
import java.nio.File.{FileSystems => FS}
...
FS.getDefault().getPath("gcs://foo", "/bar")
(edited)
```

I tried

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.{FileSystems => BFS}
BFS.matchNewResource("gcs://foo", isDirectory=true).resolve("/bar", ...).getFileName
```

but that returns only `bar` (I could do some hacky stuff, but is there a proper way for this?)

Answer (score 1):

Directory paths need to be of the form `bar/` (no preceding slash and should have a training slash).

So joining paths, which end in directories looks like:

```
BFS.matchNewResource("gcs://foo", isDirectory=true)
  .resolve("bar/", RESOLVE_DIRECTORY)
  .toString()
```